# Linux While loop/ If statement query

Tags: linux, if-statement, while-loop

I have a script that I cannot get to work, despite my best efforts. I really hope someone can help. Very new to programming, so still learning the ropes. I'm building an interactive shell script that requires the user to put in an operand, and then another operand, to produce the maths table for the 2nd operand. e.g. I select "+" & number "2" (from a range of 15), and it prints out the table for "2+1=3, 2+2 =4" etc. to a range of 10. Here is my current script;

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Please select the function you wish to perform from the following list"
echo " Multiplication = *"
echo " Addition = +"
echo " Subtraction = -"
echo " Division = /"
echo " Exponent = ^"

read s

echo "Please select a number between 1 and 15"
read n
i = 1
while [$i â€˝ le 10]
do
if [$s = "*"]
then
        echo "$n x $i = $((n*i))";

elif [ $s = "+"]
        echo "$n + $i = $((n+i))";
elif [$s = "-"]
        echo "$n - $i = $((n-i))";
elif [$s = "/"]
        echo "$n / $i = $((n/i))";
elif [$s = "^"]
        echo "$n ^ $i = $((n^i))";
fi
i = $((i+1))
done
```

I know my while loop is incorrect, so I would really appreciate any help here! Thank you!

Comment: Run your script through shellcheck: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You need spaces areound all `[` and `]`.

Comment: Your while-loop as printed here says: `[$i â€˝ le 10]`. Remove the `â€˝` and substitute a common dash: `-le`, to get: `while [ $i -le 10 ]`.

Comment: Double quote your non-integer var. references, like so: "$s".

Comment: Use `case` instead of an if/else chain.  `case "$s" in \*) ... ;; +) ...;; -) ...;; ... esac`  But you don't even need that, as you can use `eval`.  (which has other issues)

Comment: Thank you Roadowl & William. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

After some modifications :

```
    #!/bin/sh
    echo "Please select the function you wish to perform from the following list"
    echo " Multiplication = *"
    echo " Addition = +"
    echo " Subtraction = -"
    echo " Division = /"
    echo " Exponent = ^"

    read s
    echo "Please select a number between 1 and 15"
    read n
    i=1
    while [ "$i" -le 10 ] 
    do
    if [ "$s" = "*" ]; then
        echo "$n x $i = $((n*i))";

    elif [ "$s" = "+" ]; then
            echo "$n + $i = $((n+i))";
    elif [ "$s" = "-" ]; then
            echo "$n - $i = $((n-i))";
    elif [ "$s" = "/" ]; then
            echo "$n / $i = $((n/i))";
    elif [ "$s" = "^" ]; then
            echo "$n ^ $i = $((n^i))";
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
    done
```